# How to get a comma separated table of installed Windows programs using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, tabular

I need to get a list of installed programs on my computer (Windows 10) in a comma separated format showing the name of the program and version in a format like this: *Program Name,Version*

What I have tried:

I am currently using this Windows PowerShell command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Format-Table –AutoSize
```

This gets me a table that looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to look something like this (The table header format is not important):

[image]

Is there a way to format the table that would accomplish this or another PowerShell command that would produce an output similar to the second table?

Comment: Why do you want this? Sounds like an X-Y problem to me. Format-Table exists to create human friendly displays. Are you trying to creata a CSV?

Comment: I would actually like to be able to change the formatting from commas to other delimiters (example: periods, colons, etc), which I can do outside of PowerShell if needed, I just wrote the question for commas - I'm pretty new to using PowerShell and this was the solution I found for getting a list of installed programs but if there is a better way to get a csv with the same information I could work with that instead.

Comment: In that case use Kory's answer but specify whatever delimiters you want.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

See also `Export-Csv`.